# Postgresql 9.6 best settings for large admin work (min_wal and max_wal)

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, maintenance, postgresql-performance

We have a server that's disconnected from the world. It's a high end system with 48GB memory and 500GB SSD hard disk, 16 core CPUs. We're trying to do a `pg_restore` of a simple database dump of less than 10 tables, no binary data or blobs, just simple text (a comments system). But one table has about 200GB of data, so it's large.

There's no other jobs for this DB. Only this maintenance task. What are the best settings for this purpose given the config above? [PGSQL's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-MIN-WAL-SIZE) does not help me too much. My specific question is around wal settings.

If we're OK with using the whole of this server just to do a `pg_restore`, and nothing else other than PG is on this server, what settings should we use? This is what we have now:

```
maintenance_work_mem = 1500MB 
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
wal_level = minimal
full_page_writes = off
wal_buffers = 64MB
#-----  checkpoint_segments = 512
#-----  max_wal_size = (3 * checkpoint_segments) * 16MB
#-- min_wal_size = 100MB    # 80MB is the default
max_wal_size = 24576MB   # based on 512 checkpoint_segments 
max_wal_senders = 0
wal_keep_segments = 0
archive_mode = off
autovacuum = off
```

Note that using top, we find that memory is not the issue. The CPU cores are spiking to 100 or so, and then dipping. This is an intensive write process, so that makes sense. Welcome any simple-to-understand guidance on how the `min_wal_size` should be set -- note that it's commented for us now.

Comment: Previously posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/43082850/398670

Comment: I don't mind, I just cross reference things when I notice so that someone who later comes along to answer or to learn from it doesn't waste time if there are answers on the other one.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you only want to test if the restoration of the dump works and nothing more, which means you can do some unsafe configuration changes. Let's first start with your settings.

These one are a good call:

```
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
full_page_writes = off
wal_level = minimal
autovacuum = off
```

These three are only important if you are using replication, and because you already set `wal_level` to minimum, you are not using it, so they are not important:

```
wal_keep_segments = 0
archive_mode = off
max_wal_senders = 0
```

You have a lot of RAM which won't be used for anything, I would bump this one up even more:

```
maintenance_work_mem = 3GB
```

I would leave `wal_buffers` to it's default:

```
wal_buffers = -1
```

and bump `shared_buffers` (`wall_buffers` will be automatically calculated):

```
shared_buffers: 4GB
```

What you should try to concentrate is to have no, or as less checkpoints as you can during your restore. Checkpoints are controlled by `max_wal_size` and `checkpoint_timeout`. First of bump `checkpoint_timeout` to something like `20h`, so that a timed checkpoint never happens while you restore:

```
checkpoint_timeout = 20h
```

Then you can set `max_wal_size` to a value as high as your disk space allows you. If your restored DB is `200GB` and your disk `500GB`, you should be safe to set `max_wal_size` to `100GB` because Postgres can store up to two checkpoints of wals (which is 2x`max_wal_size`):

```
max_wal_size = 100GB
```

`min_wal_size` won't matter that much in your case, but you can probably bump it to 10GB

```
min_wal_size = 10GB
```

I would also recommend that you use `pg_restore` with `--jobs=NUM` where NUM would probably be the number of CPU cores, but it also depends on the speed of your `SSD`, so you can play with this parameter.

Besides Postgres settings, I would also recommend that if possible you add an additional `SATA` drive (`7200RPM` will be fine) and symlink `pg_wal` directory to that `SATA` disk. That is the directory where Postgres saves WALs, and because they are written in append, `SATA` is fast enough for them. It will reduced the load on the `SSD`, but will also mean you will be able to bump `max_wal_size` even more (depending on the size of the `SATA` disk).

Finally don't forget to restore your settings to the sane values after the dump is restored.

Comment: How does increasing `checkpoint_timeout` value prevent checkpoint from happening?
Increasing `checkpoint_timeout` the time when a checkpoint can time out, it does not prevent timeout, isn't it?

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-CHECKPOINTS) `checkpoint_timeout` is: "Maximum time between automatic WAL checkpoints." This means that if a checkpoint didn't occur because of `max_wal_size` it will be automatically done every `checkpoint_timeout` time, e.g. if `checkpoint_timeout=5m` a checkpoint will be done every 5 minutes if there was no checkpoint for 5 minutes. We increase it so that a checkpoint doesn't happen during the pg_restore.

Answer (score 0):

I've given a +1 to Strahinja's answer, but have more to add than is likely to fit in a comment, so adding an answer.

The only quibble I have with any advice from Strahinja is that the optimal WAL sizes may vary depending on hardware and OS.  I have seen benchmarks where leaving sizes at the default performed better than boosting them for restoring a dump.  That was a surprise, but it does happen sometimes.  If you do boost them, I would recommend setting the sizes to equal values not more than a third of the size of that dedicated drive that was recommended.

I'm fine with disabling autovacuum for this purpose, but be sure not to consider your restore done until you run `VACUUM ANALYZE;` as a database superuser in the database.  This will set hint bits and build the visibility map and free space map efficiently, rather than that burdening your foreground queries at first.  The statistics will help with good planning.

And be absolutely sure you set the configuration back to a sane production configuration and restart the database service before starting any production work on the system!

Comment: When you say "WAL sizes" you mean the values for `min_wal_size` and `max_wal_size`? Right? If that is the case, I don't understand what would different hardware specs have anything to do with those two parameters, they only change how much disk space will be used up by WALs and how often will the CHECKPOING be done. In this case the more the better, because we want to avoid a `CHECKPOINT` as much as possible so the restore is as fast as possible.

Good point about restoring back to the sane defaults. Will add it to my answer.

Comment: @StrahinjaKustudic Yeah, I meant `min_wal_size` and `max_wal_size`.  My best guess as to why the tiny default may have performed well in some circumstances (especially a bulk load with no concurrent database activity) is that the RAID controller with non-volatile cache may have hit the few WAL files so fast as the WAL files rotated that many of the writes to spinning rust got skipped.